# Is there a way to reduce the size of the Spacy installation?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I'm using [Spacy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy) in a project and noticed that my Docker images are pretty big. A bit of research led me to find out that just the Spacy installation itself (in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy`) accounts for `267MB`, so I was wondering if there's anything that can be done to reduce that footprint?

Comment: Do you have space issue?

Comment: Not a storage issue, but my Docker image ends up at ~700MB, so between continuous integration building and pushing it to a Docker registry, devs that depend on that image downloading it whenever there's a change... a lot of bandwidth that I'd rather not have to use. Even if this was a complete non-issue, I'm interested in knowing if there's anything that can be done to reduce Spacy's footprint.

Comment: The current version (2.2) is much smaller, but one thing you could also do in an older installation, is remove some of the language data for languages you don't care about. Those are in `spacy/lang/*`.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, SpaCy's 2.2 was released yesterday (Oct 2nd, 2019).

One of the product features for this 2.2 is "[Smaller disk foot-print, better language resource handling](https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-v2-2#lookups)". So, upgrading to SpaCy 2.2. may be one way to reduce the size of a SpaCy installation.

(Although this post doesn't solve your specific problem, I believe it does answer this specific question.)

Comment: Agreed that that is probably the best solution. As an indication, my 2.1.8 installation was 408MB, the 2.2.2 installation only 55.2MB.

Comment: Yeah, I've been tracking the Github issue they had to address this. I haven't had the chance to move to the latest version yet, but I agree it addresses this concern quite nicely.
@SofieVL congrats on becoming part of the team!